# Nonlinear optimization with symbolic constraint in Matlab

Tags: matlab, mathematical-optimization, symbolic-math

I need to solve a nonlinear problem in *n* symbolic variables. The objective function to maximize is just a sum/difference of products of a variable with itself or with another one, so it is basically a quadratic equation.

The problem is that I need to impose a symbolic limit on the sum of these variables, as well as limit the values of these variables to be between 0 and 1 inclusive.

So I need an upper bound expressed as a function of the (symbolic) sum and not as a number. Can Matlab solve such kind of problems? If yes, how?

EDIT: Basically I need to perform the optimization of a symbolic problem with a quadratic objective function and linear constraints.

Comment: What is a "symbolic limit"? Why do you need to use symbolic math at all? Have you tried `fmincon`?

Comment: "symbolic limit" means that the sum of the variables should be equal to a value A, without knowing the actual value of A. So the solution should be in terms of the symbolic variable A (i.e. an equation in terms of A).

Comment: Nonlinear optimization and symbolic math are not generally compatible with each other. You probably just need to write a regular numeric function to define your constraint. Try `fmincon`. I can't provide much more as your question is much to general.